# Find_or_initializes_by for a complex model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Newbie Rails user here so sorry if I'm totally overlooking something; I'm just looking for direction on what resources I should use to solve this problem.

I have a Rails app running that uses virtual attributes to define a complicated has_many :through relationship. What I'm looking to do is to use the id of an existing entry rather than creating a new one when a user submits a form. I have attempted to use find_or_initializes_by and find_or_create to no avail. Depending on how I set it up, it either changes one of the diagnosis columns on the join table successfully (but leaves the other diagnosis column blank, causing a rollback), or it doesn't work at all.

Background for my use case: a Case can have many diagnoses (Diagnosis), some of which are primary, and others are "differential" diagnoses. Cases and multiple diagnoses are related in a join table.

My current setup:

```
case.rb
def new
  @case = Case.new
  @case_and_diagnoses = @case.case_and_diagnoses.build
  @primary_diagnoses = @case_and_diagnoses.build_primary_diagnosis
  @differential_diagnoses = @case_and_diagnoses.build_differential_diagnosis
end
```

The relevant section of the case form:

```
<%= f.fields_for        :case_and_diagnoses do |x| %>
  <%= x.fields_for      :primary_diagnosis do |diagnosis| %>
    <%= diagnosis.label            :name, "Diagnosis" %>
    <%= diagnosis.text_field       :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= x.fields_for      :differential_diagnosis do |differential| %>
    <%= differential.label         :name, 'Differential diagnosis' %>
    <%= differential.text_field    :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What's the best way to tackle this problem? I don't need an explicit code block to use, but I'm looking for a strategy so I can maybe find my own way. Thank you very much!

**Update:**

The models:

```
class Case < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :get_diagnoses

  belongs_to :submitter, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'submitter_id'
  belongs_to :resident, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'resident_id'
  belongs_to :faculty, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'faculty_id'
  has_one :service
  has_many :case_and_diagnoses
  has_many :primary_diagnoses, through: :case_and_diagnoses
  has_many :differential_diagnoses, through: :case_and_diagnoses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :case_and_diagnoses
end

class Diagnosis < ApplicationRecord
has_many :case_and_diagnoses
has_many :cases, through: :case_and_diagnoses
end

class CaseAndDiagnosis < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :case
  belongs_to :primary_diagnosis, class_name: 'Diagnosis', foreign_key: :primary_diagnosis_id, optional: true
  belongs_to :differential_diagnosis, class_name: 'Diagnosis', foreign_key: :differential_diagnosis_id, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_diagnosis, :differential_diagnosis
end
```

Comment: Can you show your model so we can see what you have currently. It will help

Comment: Done! Case.rb has some additional information unrelated to the issue (users stuff, primarily). Thank you for having a look!